# inheriting user control from a base class

Tags: wpf

I've done lots of searching and found lots of answers but for some reason it's not working for me. I have a VB app in WPF. I want some common code for user controls.

So I make a base class like this:

```
Public Class cU
    Inherits UserControl
    Public Value As Double
End Class
```

And a user control, the Xaml starts like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl3"
```

So all I have to do, as far as I can see, is to change this to:

```
<local:cU x:Class="UserControl3"
```

But although no error is shown in the Xaml window, I get and error in the error list:
"local" is an undeclared prefix. Line 1. position 2.' XML is not valid

(by the way, when I did exactly this in winrt it worked fine)

I tried changing it to local to Controls and also putting cU in a namespace called local but it doesn't change.

Comment: Did you add the XML namespace declaration for `local`? Something like `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"`.

Comment: sorry, where exactly does that go?

Comment: `<local:cU x:Class="UserControl3" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:..." ...`

Comment: oh, I see this further down in the user control definition:    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"

Comment: Then you should write `<my:cU x:Class="UserControl3" ...`

Comment: Thanks, tried that, but still not quite there (see below)

Comment: Clemens, you were right, it was not working as I had a namespace around my cU class from an earlier attempt, I got rid of it then it worked fine, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add your namespace in your XAML for your window tag or control tag (depends whichever you are using).

```
<Window x:Class="YourNamespace.YourClass"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace">
```

then you can use the `<local:UserControl3 />` tag

the `YourNamespace` in your case would be `WpfApplication1`

Comment: Right, further down in my original user control code I had: xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" If I declare my user control with my:cU, the Xampl looks ok, no errors. But I still get errors when I build, in the .g.vb and the .g.i.vb intermediate files. In the .g.i.vb file it tells me to change WpfApplication1.cU to local.cU i if I do that, the error goes away, but I obviously can't be fiddling with the intermediate files. Am I getting closer?

Comment: ... and if I use <local:cU I get "local is an undeclared prefix" in the Xaml

Comment: yes what xmlns does is that it registers your namespace so you can use it in your xaml file. You don't have to change namespace of your project just declare the namespace in your xaml file. Declare (in your case) `xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"` after its declared you can use it in your xaml like this `<local:UserControl3  />`. You don't have to change any namespace in your project. Also,  what error does the debugger give out?